# How can i map this part of the ER to relational schema and what can be the appropriate attributes?

Tags: database, relational-database, subclass, entity-relationship, superclass

Part of the ER diagram [here](http://sdrv.ms/100X2bj).

Here, Customer is the super-class, with Private and Business being the sub-classes with a disjoint mandatory participation, and Business customers is a super-class of Silver, Gold and Diamond sub-classes respectively again with a disjoint mandatory participation

A quick explanation: Customers are divided into Business and Private. Business customers have three membership options: Silver:10% Discount, Gold:25% Discount, Diamond:40% Discount. What is the best way to map the above into a Relational Schema? What will be differentiating attributes and generic attributes? 
Currently, I have come up with the following:

4 tables - PrivateCustomer(From Customer Superclass) and SilverMember, GoldMember and DiamondMember (From Business Superclass)

`PrivateCustomer (CuID, CuFirstName, CuLastName, CuDOB, CompanyName, CuAddressLine1, CuAddressLine2, PhoneNumber, CuEmail, CuNotes,
CuLocID)`

`SilverMember (CuID, ????? DiscPerc, DiscAccrued,
CuLocID)`

`GoldMember (CuID, ???? DiscPerc, DiscAccrued,
CuLocID)`

`DiamondMember (CuID, ???? DiscPerc, DiscAccrued,
CuLocID)`

**CuLocID** is a Foreign Key to remove transitive dependencies relating to Post Code, City, Country (Location details that are stored in a different table - **tblCuLoc**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think your ERM is bad design, because you should better use a role pattern instead of putting them into entities. In other words the membership options `Silver`, `Gold` and `Diamond` are no entities.

To answer your question, you have three options to map your classes:

1. All attributes of the class hierarchy goes into one table (*Single Table Inheritance*).
2. All attributes of each class goes into a separate table (*Class Table Inheritance*).
3. All attributes of all non abstract classes goes into a separate table (*Concrete Table Inheritance*).

But honestly you should revise your ERM before. At least you should create a entity for the discount membership (e.g. `Discount Group`) with the attributes `Percentage`, `Name` and a one-to-many relationship between your `Business Customer` entity and your `Discount Group` entity. You could also use the role pattern for the customer entity itself, instead using sub classes for them. Here is my proposal as an ERM in the UML to improve the discount membership:

[image: Proposal to improve the original ERM]

Mapping this to a relational schema by using e.g. the 2. approach (*Class Table Inheritance*) you would have the following relations:

- `customer(id, ...)`
- `business_customer(id, ...)`
- `private_customer(id, ...)`
- `discount_membership(customer_id, group_id, discount_accrued)`
- `discount_group(id, name, discount_percantage)`

To force the multiplicity in `discount_membership` you should use a unique contraints on the column `customer_id` and of course the proper foreign key contraints.

Comment: Would you elaborate on how can i use a role pattern in the present scenario. Thanks.

Comment: You should use an entity like `Discount Group`. With this you'll need just a one-to-many relationship between your customers and the discount group.

Comment: Does single table inheritance mean you just have one table for Customer (the superclass) and you have attributes like: CustomerType: Business or Private, MemberType: Gold, Silver or Diamond, and other attributes which may be null?

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but if use `Discount Group` as a table i can only inculcate the Membership options. Right? How about the Customer type?

Comment: Sorry! I now understand what you meant. I have a database assignment and i consider myself average on the subject. I have no idea, how i'm going to get through :( But you have been very helpful thanks again...

Comment: You are right about the single table inheritance, you need a column for the type and you have a sparse matrix! Which approach you choose depends on your needs.

Comment: One last question:

Would you mind showing me, how my relational schema might look, after I consider the **Discount group** as an entity. I mean, do I need to bring Business Customer into the picture?

Comment: Should I post a graphic ERM into my answer for the discount group? This might need so time (20 min).

Comment: That would be very kind of you. Much appreciated. Thanks